# Block download of a file if slow response time

Tags: java, android, download

I'm trying to download a file and am having problems. This is my code:

```
URL website = new URL(url);
rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

for downloading a generic file, but in some cases, the site is slow to reply and I want to detect and block the download for this reason.

Is this possible and how can I do this

Comment: Your code won't work anyway. You have to call the transfer methods in a loop. If you need to detect slowness you'll have to use a conventional read/write loop and set a read timeout,